# transforming UITableView to support right to left languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView`, I want to apply some  transformation on it so it will support right to left languages, what I did is the following:

```
       for(UITableViewCell *cell in self.RSSNewsTableView.visibleCells) {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*0.0174532925);
        cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180*0.0174532925);       
        cell.detailTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);             
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
       // cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(2*M_PI);

    }
```

and what I got is the following:

[image]

what is the right transformation for the `detailTextLabel` so it will be placed correctly under cell's `textLabel` ?

Answer (score 0):

i personally would not implement that with a affine transformation, just create new labels and custom views and position them yourself with the autoresizingmask

i looked at my iPhone with the arabic language and the default navigation still goes to the left, so there is no need to turn the green disclosure indicator in your screenshot.