# upside down transformation for any view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

how to make any view (let's say a `UIButton`) to look upside down using transformations in `Quartz` ? I've tried `button1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);` with many other values (other than M_PI) but nothing worked correctly.

Comment: What specifically happened after you tried this?

Comment: it transforms horizontally and flipped, i want it to return to its original state (flipped to normal), maybe i misspelled the question: i want that label to return to side down up state.

Comment: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);` rotates the image. You want to reverse and rotate the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);` rotates the image anchoring the top left corner. If you wish to anchor the center, you will need to move the `UIButton` before or after the transform.

Your comments read like you want to reverse and rotate the image.

Comment: how to reposition the UIButton after rotation ?

Comment: thanks dude, as a mathematician would you please refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545185/transforming-uitableview-to-support-right-to-left-languages